# Direction of tension?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, statics

[image]

If you draw the free body diagram of the frame above, what direction would the tension force acting on the frame be - to the right or down? Because the rope it horizontal at some points but vertical at others.

THanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tension_(physics)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are some of the Newtonian couples. The weight pulls down on the rope, and the rope pulls up on the weight(tension). The **rope pulls down on the pulley(tension)**, and the pulley pulls up on the rope. The pulley pulls right on the rope , and the **rope pulls left on the pulley(tension)**. the rope pulls right on the frame (tension), and the frame pulls left on the rope.

The ones in bold are the ones you have drawn...